# How to change as3 code in a class file

Tags: actionscript-3

I am working on some jigsaw puzzles for children on the iPad.

This code is working fine for 3 puzzles, but it is a lot of code that i repeat and i am wondering how to change the code so it will be possible to use a class file. Hope someone can help me with this.

```
var puzzel1:Array = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16];
var puzzel1k:Array = [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, t12, t13, t14, t15, t16];

for each(var current_piece:MovieClip in puzzel1){
    current_piece.visible = true;
    current_piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag_piece_puzzel1);
    current_piece.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stop_piece_puzzel1);
}

for each(var target_piece:MovieClip in puzzel1k){
    target_piece.visible = true;
}

//alle pieces van puzzel 1 worden hiermee gedragd
function drag_piece_puzzel1(e: MouseEvent): void {
    current_piece = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
    current_piece.startDrag();
    current_piece.scaleX = 0.85;
    current_piece.scaleY = 0.85;
    addChild(current_piece);
    if(current_piece == p1){target_piece = t1;}
    if(current_piece == p2){target_piece = t2;}
    if(current_piece == p3){target_piece = t3;}
    if(current_piece == p4){target_piece = t4;}
    if(current_piece == p5){target_piece = t5;}
    if(current_piece == p6){target_piece = t6;}
    if(current_piece == p7){target_piece = t7;}
    if(current_piece == p8){target_piece = t8;}
    if(current_piece == p9){target_piece = t9;}
    if(current_piece == p10){target_piece = t10;}
    if(current_piece == p11){target_piece = t11;}
    if(current_piece == p12){target_piece = t12;}
    if(current_piece == p13){target_piece = t13;}
    if(current_piece == p14){target_piece = t14;}
    if(current_piece == p15){target_piece = t15;}
    if(current_piece == p16){target_piece = t16;}
}



function stop_piece_puzzel1(e: MouseEvent): void {

    current_piece.stopDrag();

    if (target_piece.hitTestObject(current_piece)) {
        current_piece.scaleX = 1;
        current_piece.scaleY = 1;
        current_piece.x = target_piece.x;           
        current_piece.y = target_piece.y;
        if (array_pieces.indexOf(current_piece) == -1) {
            counter = counter +1;
            puzzlepiece = current_piece;
            array_pieces.push(this["puzzlepiece"]);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of learning resources: - - https://www.google.com/search?q=OOP+actionscript&gbv=1&sei=FQGtVon5C4PB-wHzia3QBA

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but here is a quick one based on the fact that your `puzzel1` and `puzzel1k` arrays are lined up:

all of the lines that are like this:
`if(current_piece == p1){target_piece = t1;}`

Could be replaced with a couple of lines like:

`var current_piece_index:int = puzzel1.indexOf(current_piece);
target_piece = puzzel1k[current_piece_index];`

**Another solution** would be to use a `Dictionary` which is like an array, but instead of being in positions like `[0]` and `[4]`, the keys are other objects.

To set it up you would iterate through your arrays of pieces, using the pieces as keys and the targets as the associated values, like this:

`var targetsByPieces:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
for(var i:uint = 0; i<puzzel1.length; i++){
    targetsByPieces[puzzel1[i]] = puzzel1k[i];
}`

Then to use it you would just look up the target so all your `if(current_piece == p1){target_piece = t1;}` code is replaced by one line:

`target_piece = targetsByPieces[current_piece];`

Neither of these solutions deal with the possibility of there not being a matched target for the piece in play - but usually jigsaws don't have 'spare pieces' so I imagine this isn't an issue for you.